# How to set the height of combo box in mudselect

Tags: mudblazor

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkcHunlIIlhnhhXc

How do I set the height of the combo box. I tried setting Style="height:200px" but that didnot work

Comment: All input components have same style height for UI consistency for example when you have multiple in a form. Why you want to change the height of the select input? (Asking to better understand your problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the specific class. Which in this case is `mud-select-input`

```
<style>
.mud-select-input
{
    height:200px;
}
</style>
```

[mudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOmduxcPiHUUcIsX)

Comment: What if I have two select boxes and want to set the height of only one and not the other?

Comment: What if I have two select boxes and want to set the height of only one and not the other?

Comment: @Venkat By giving the selectbox you want changed a class and styling that classes .mud-select-input only. [snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEQHkHmASiTXxtYv)

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to reduce the height of a MudSelect to make it look better (in my case), a much easier way is to set Margin to Margin.Dense.

Documents here:
https://www.mudblazor.com/components/select#props-margin

Sanbox here:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYcdELPXPhpPFPvc